# Why can't I switch equipment, vanity items, or clothes?

Tags: terraria-mobile

Is there any reason I can't switch inventory items?  For example, when I hold a helmet, to put it on, I hold it to the equipment menu (the one with my head on it). It opens I put it over my other helmet, and release it, but, it just goes back to my inventory.

Comment: this is very odd

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the equipment tab and then move your armor back into your inventory and only then can you equip you new armor from your inventory.  And i don't think there are maps.

Answer (score -2):

You need to take off the armour you have on then try to put it on

Comment: This adds nothing not covered by the other answer.